# What preposition should I use before 'molecular level'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What preposition should I use before 'molecular level'?

I'm going to make an example, which I totally made up, just for clarity.

> The presence of this organism within the liver causes changes **on/at** (a) molecular level.

What I mean is that these changes will occur because of their influence on the liver's molecules.

I ran a search on [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occur%20at%20molecular%20level%2Coccur%20at%20a%20molecular%20level%2Coccur%20on%20a%20molecular%20level&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccur%20at%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccur%20at%20a%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccur%20on%20a%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coccur%20at%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccur%20at%20a%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccur%20on%20a%20molecular%20level%3B%2Cc0), and 'on a' seems to be the winner, but not by much, so I would like to hear someone else's opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "at a level" and "on a level" are used in different contexts. For any given context, such as your specific example, there may be one that has become more idiomatic through use, or there may be a logical reason why one is correct.

Generally speaking, "at" means that you have reached something, but are not necessarily in it, or on it. For example - if you were in an elevator and you reached the 4th floor, you might say "I'm *at* the 4th floor". However, once you stepped out of the elevator and onto the floor you might say "I'm *on* the 4th floor".

Saying something is operating "at a level" suggests that they are *parallel* with it. But saying that something is operating "*on* a level" suggests some involvement or interactivity with other things that are also on that level.

I'm no expert in the field that you're speaking about, but I would guess that "operating on a molecular level" means that something is actually interacting with molecules, which would explain why "on" is the idiomatic preposition.